# Emacs Lisp - bind `(` to `(<cur>)` and `()` to `()`

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've gotten a nice rebind, `(` to `(<cur>)` working, but I would like to be able to still type `()` to do `()<cur>`. Is this possible in Emacs Lisp?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Most/all "paren-pairing" packages do that for you, for example.  You might like to start with `electric-pair-mode` which comes bundled with recent Emacsen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to get a character,

```
(interactive "c`)' will insert ), else will go inside and insert")
```

Then just test if the parameter is equal to `41` (close parens).